# How do I fix the graphics output on my imac 21.5" late 2009

Tags: boot, graphics, mac

I have been exploring the possibility of installing Ubuntu 18.04 on my imac 21.5" late 2009. I made a USB boot key, booted the machine.

Ubuntu seems to be booting ok, but the graphics output is split and duplicated into 4 ways, the colours are all faded and text is almost unreadable. I'm worried that if I go the full install, the graphics output will be the same.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Hi Phill and welcome to askubuntu! Open a terminal after you have booted with your usb boot key, and type `hwinfo --short` . This will help to identify your laptop. Add the output to your post.

Comment: The best way to identify: `sudo apt install inxi` and then type `inxi -b` . This show all basic infos in a short way.